# Unable to convert Swift protocol in Objective-C || How to write 'Self' return type of a protocol method of Swift in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I want to use a protocol in Objective-C class, which is declared in Swift. For that I have added the '@objc' inference in protocol declaration as well as at the method declaration.

I am getting an error on method declaration in protocol, while compiling:

"Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C"

```
@objc protocol DataProcessor {
    @objc static func compute(from object: [String: Any]) -> [Self]
    // The above method declaration gives me this error.
}
```

"this method will return an array of an instance types of the class which is confirming this protocol"

I am stuck as I don't want to convert the Objective-C class as it is huge and I also don't want to use this Swift protocol as it is used all over the app.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you return `SwiftProtocol` instead of `Self`? Because it seems the `Self` will always conforms `SwiftProtocol`. But not sure it will be available in Obj-C.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have an analogue for Self, so it can't be used. There are a few strategies to try and get around these constraints, but it depends on how you're using it. (which you didn't share)

Comment: The fact that you are using `Any?` tells me that you have other more serious problems.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I have edited my question more precisely. Hope it would be helpful to understand.

Comment: Do you need the return type to be the actual type of the class or is it sufficient if the return type is `DataProcessor`? If it is the latter, you can simply change `Self` to `DataProcessor`.

Comment: I need the actual type of the class in return.

Comment: I see that you were able to get an answer to this question from the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90919). Perhaps you could post what you learned here, as an answer to your own question, to help others who come across this and aren't members of the Apple Developer Forums (especially since your question was voted up and favorited, a sure sign that others are looking for an answer, too)!

Comment: Finally I end-up in returning the 'Protocol' instead of 'Self' as everyone suggested above and then un-wrapped it with the expected class type in the caller class. And I have to change a bit of my code to incorporate this change. I up-voted your replies. Thank you everyone.